# GitHub actions, my self hosted runner is off, how can I turn in on

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions

My GitHub action runner agent is hosted in AWS, and once I run ./run.sh, it waits and listens for the job.
The issue is that my self-hosted runner in GitHub is off.
How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to install it so it will [run as a service](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service).  That documentation outlines the steps to install it this way, and it states

> You can configure the self-hosted runner application as a service to
> automatically start the runner application when the machine starts.

You could alternatively run it in the background using nohup so it keeps running once the user logs off if you aren't doing it as a service:

```
/usr/bin/nohup ./run.sh &
```

[These troubleshooting tips](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-self-hosted-runners) can also be useful if your runner goes offline.